# How to encode properly non 7bits ASCII characters with sqlplus host echo

Tags: oracle, unicode, encoding, sqlplus

[image]I some scripts I just echo some information to log program.
Unfortunately, although NLS_LANG = AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8 I am only able to display output with ASCII 7 bits.

```
sqlplus /nolog
host echo %NLS_LANG%
host echo "an OK test with ASCII 7 bit characters"
host echo "a KO test with accentuated characters : àéùôù"
```

Edit : it is a problem with unicode file (UTF-8)

Comment: Try running this and see what it brings back: @.[%NLS_LANG%]

Comment: It's not about Oracle really, it's about what the Windows command shell can handle properly. You ought to be able to do \chcp 65001` before starting SQL\*PLus to get full UTF-8 support, but it just drops out to the command prompt when you do the final host call, even with \cmd /u`. [As this article suggests](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html), you might need to use PowerShell.

Comment: @Ageonix C:\Users\jblanchard>@[%NLS_LANG%]
'[AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8]' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne

Comment: @Alex Poole Thanks I understand than classic command shell doesn't give full UTF-8 support. I will try with powershell. My first tries with power shell give some error, i will make further investigations and make a feedback.

Answer (score 3):

You must set the codepage of your `cmd` window, since SQL*Plus inherits it.

Run `chcp 65001` before you launch sqlplus.

However, there is an issue with UTF-8 on command line window, see [how to use sqlplus with utf8 on windows command line](https://community.oracle.com/thread/600575): *works [only] for characters [...] if the first character in a line is ASCII (code < 128, e.g. blank)*

Perhaps [Codepage 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) also fulfill your needs:

```
chcp 1252
set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252
sqlplus ...
```

Comment: thanks for the tip but with  chcp 65001, in sqlplus the command host echo "a KO test with accentuated characters : àéùôù"  makes a strange effect : sqlplus exit (or crash).

Comment: with chcp 1252 it's better, it's possible to see accentuated characters (but in my case files are in UTF-8 so I can't use this solution for proper echo)

Comment: For the link it's interesting jI will ask the C filters written by the author.